# why when I print the variable v1, it is not printed in lower case, even though I apply the .lower() method?

Tags: python

```
>>> v1 = "BOSTON"    
>>> v1.lower()    
'boston'    
>>> print(v1)    
BOSTON
```

Comment: `v1.lower()` *produced* a lower-case version of the string - but you didn't assign it to a variable, or otherwise do anything with the resulting value.

Answer (score 1):

`v1.lower()` does not modify (mutate) `v1`. It returns a new value that is the lowercase version of `v1`. If you want `v1` to be converted to lowercase itself you would do:

```
v1 = "BOSTON"
v1 = v1.lower()
print(v1)
```

this then gives you:

```
"boston"
```